# Firing an Event from Global Javascript to Livewire emitting twice simultaneously

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

So I have a basic workflow:
This project is done with laravel.

In my livewire blade file:

```js
<script>
 window.addEventListener('triggerPayment', event => {
   ... some code

    callback: function (data) {
      console.log("how many times is this printed"); //---> this is printed once
      window.Livewire.emit('transactionCallback', data);
    },
   ... some code
});  
</script>
```

In my livewire component

```php
 protected $listeners = ['transactionCallback'];

 public function transactionCallback($data)
 {
   \Log::info($data); //----------------> this is logged twice
 }
```

So the problem is, this event is fired twice and I'm not sure why. The `console.log` statement only gets printed once, so I'm sure it's not from the blade file.
However, the `window.livewire.emit` fires two identical simultaneous events, the only difference being the livewire ID.
When I inspect the log file, I see two entries which further proves the event was emitted twice. Also inspecting the browser Network tab displays two network request sent.

This becomes very problematic because the resulting livewire method this event fires to saves some data in the database. This was resulting in duplicate entries being saved into the database.

I rewrote the database function to use an `updateOrCreate` but this keeps resulting  in a `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry` given that there's a column which is unique.

I'm not sure how to work around this. I've tried figuring out why two network request are sent and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: When two identical console.log events happens simultaneously, it will be written in one string with the number of actions. Are you sure it's happening only once? I would bet that triggerPayment event is happening twice for some reason. As a workaround you could debounce your callback.

Comment: Yes I am very certain it's happening once. The `console.log` output is printed with no number of actions, indicating that it was executed only once.

Comment: Then, as I said, you could try debounce workaround. https://docs-lodash.com/v4/debounce/ with lodash or other library you like. this should fix the symptoms but will not solve the problem :)

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I am facing the same exact issue.